# Autowired KafkaTemplate in SpringBoot/spring-kafka application throws null pointer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka

I'm trying to use the [spring-kafka](http://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/htmlsingle/) KafkaTemplate, inside a Spring Boot application, to write messages to a Kafka topic.

I created a KafkaConfig class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableKafka
public class KafkaConfig {

    @Value("${kafka.broker.address}")
    private String brokerAddress;

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory<Integer, String> producerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(producerConfigs());
    }

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> producerConfigs() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, brokerAddress);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, 0);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, 16384);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG, 1);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.BUFFER_MEMORY_CONFIG, 33554432);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, IntegerSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);

        return props;
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate<Integer, String> kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate<Integer, String>(producerFactory());
    }

}
```

... and Autowired the KafkaTemplate in the class where I'm writing to Kafka:

```
@Autowired
private KafkaTemplate<Integer, String> template;
```

For some reason, the autowiring doesn't appear to work. I notice that the KafkaTemplate is null when I run in debug:

[image: template is null]

This object should not be null; it should be a KafkaTemplate object. This throws a null pointer exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'watchService': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:136) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:408) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:776) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~[spring-context-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174) [spring-boot-1.4.0.RELEASE.jar:1.4.0.RELEASE]
    at io.woolford.Application.main(Application.java:11) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at io.woolford.WatchService.monitor(WatchService.java:93) ~[classes/:na]
    at io.woolford.WatchService.watchPath(WatchService.java:37) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:365) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:310) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:133) ~[spring-beans-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
```

kafka-spring has worked well for me in the past using almost identical code, and so I'm a bit confused why the Autowiring isn't working this time. Can you see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The problem cannot be reproducible. The GitHub repo is down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the bean too soon...

```
postProcessBeforeInitialization
```

...that's invoked before the properties are set.

**EDIT**

Implement `SmartLifecycle` and move

```
watchService.monitor(path);
```

to `start()`.

**EDIT2**

That said; this is weird...

```
    WatchService watchService = new WatchService();
    watchService.monitor(path);
```

You are creating a new instance in the post construct method - of course it won't be autowired because it's not managed by Spring.

Comment: See my new edit - your `WatchService` instance is not Spring-managed.

Comment: Thanks so much, @GaryRussell. You were right about the `WatchService` not being managed by Spring. I moved the `@Postconstruct` to the `monitor` method and deleted the `watchPath` method (which contained the  `new WatchService()`.

Comment: i do have the same problem now, but i did not get your point this is what my service class looks and config class is same as above`@Service
public class ReportingInventoryError {
 @Value("${kafka.producer.inventorycountupdate.errortopic}")
 private String topicName;
 
 @Autowired
 private KafkaTemplate<String, ReportingTask> template;
 
 public void start() {
  ReportingTask task = new ReportingTask();
  ReportingTask.TaskDetails details = new ReportingTask.TaskDetails();
     template.send(topicName,"messageKey",task.setTaskDetails(details));
  
 }

} .   @GaryRussell

Comment: Don't put code in comments. It's hard to read. And don't ask new questions in comments on 2 year old answers. Ask a new question instead.

Comment: @GaryRussell, I am having similar problem with this one. Can you check it out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53005694/autowired-kafka-template-null-exception